# CU3ER open source alternative

Tags: javascript, flash, slideshow

Does anyone know either a javascript or flash based alternative for CU3ER?
It was open source but has since changed: http://getcu3er.com/

Comment: I doubt anything made with JS will work in any browsers except for Chrome and maybe Firefox, as the JS required for such effects is quite intense.

Comment: Ok so flash may be the only feasible method...

Comment: CCslider appears to be a html5 css3 slideshow that works... http://codecanyon.net/item/ccslider-jquery-3d-slideshow-plugin/full_screen_preview/162445

Comment: Piecemaker does an effect similar to cu3er: http://active.tutsplus.com/freebies/exclusive/exclusive-freebie-the-piecemaker-2/

Comment: Yeah, the JS one is a bit laggy. I'd go with flash for this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Piecemaker
http://active.tutsplus.com/freebies/exclusive/exclusive-freebie-the-piecemaker-2/

Answer (score 1):

CU3ER is Javascript ready and supports any browser in Javascript. It's 3D in Chrome, Firefox and Safari! http://getcu3er.com/javascript http://getcu3er.com/javascript-3d

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is a nice one : [cute slider](http://www.cuteslider.com)

it's written in pure js and cross browser with smooth transitions

Comment: Any chance you are affiliated with 'cute slider'?

Comment: The title says "open source" but the link points to a purchase page. Where is the open source portion you meant to post?